# Quiero mostrar datos en un input tipo text pero solo puedo con un select laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

lo que quiero es mostrar unos datos en campo de tipo text de laravel el problema es que como los traigo en json me tira un error si lo cambio a tipo text alguna idea como podria realizarlo cuando seleccione el empleado me tire el numero de ese empleado el problema que en vez del tipo select quiero un text

```
 <div class="form-group">
          {!! Form::label('nombre', 'Nombre:', ['class' => 'col-lg-1 control-label']) !!}
          <div class="col-md-8">

          {!! Form::select('nombre_accion',$empleado,null,['placeholder'=>'Selecciona','id'=>'nombre_accion']) !!}
           </div>
           </div>
            <br>
          <br><br>
          <div class="form-group">
          {!! Form::label('identidad', '#empleado:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
          <div class="col-md-3">
          {{Form::select('num_empleado',['required'=>'required'],['id'=>'num_empleado'])}}

           </div>
           </div>



**esta es mi funicon** 


$(document).ready(function() {

    $('select[name="nombre_accion"]').on('change', function(){
        var id_nombre = $(this).val();
        if(id_nombre) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'acciones_empleado/'+id_nombre,
                type:"GET",
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data) {

                    $('select[name="num_empleado"]').empty();

                    $.each(data, function(idx, num_empleado){

                        $('select[name="num_empleado"]').append('<option value="'+ num_empleado.id +'">' + num_empleado.num_empleado + '</option>');

                    });
                },
                complete: function(){
                    $('#loader').css("visibility", "hidden");
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('select[name="num_empleado"]').empty();
        }

    });

});
```

La cual me lleva a este controlador

```
public static function acciones_empleado_get(Request $request,$id)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()){
            $empleado_accion=empleado::empleado_accion($id);
            return response()->json( $empleado_accion);
        }

    }
```

y este es mi modelo en el cual realizo la consulta

```
public static function empleado_accion($id){

        return   \DB::table('empleado')
            ->select('empleado.id','empleado.num_empleado')->where('id','=',$id)->get();

    }

}
```

Comment: ¿cuál es el error?

Comment: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\ICF\resources\views\modales\modal-registro-acciones.blade.php) (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\ICF\resources\views\modales\modal-registro-acciones.blade.php)

Comment: ese es el errror ala hora de cambiar el select por un tipo text